# How do I embed an image uploaded by form to google doc/auto generating PDF?

Tags: image, text, replace, upload

I have a google form (Medical report). Whenever someone answers the form, the answers go to a sheet and creates copy of a doc template, replaces keywords and then generates a pdf. I've create separate folders to organize the PDFs for the responses. This is working well thus far.

However, the report (Google Form) requires the user to upload an image as part of some of the answers ([Sample Form Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzUAW.png)). I would like to have two separate images automatically appear on the doc for Before Treatment and After Treatment ([To replace the sample text from google doc with pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCtYl.png)).

The image uploads to drive fine, but I don't know how to have the uploaded image appear on the Google docs and pdf. So far I'm only able to obtain a drive link instead of an actual image ([How the PDF generated file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ7DK.png))

Here's a sample of my script:

```
    Function afterFormSubmit(e) {                                                                               
    const info = e.namedValues;

    //Running the createPDF fuction into the form submission 
                                                                                                                            
    createPDF(info);                                                                                            
    }
    
    //Function to create PDF

    function createPDF(info){       
    const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("pdfFolderId");  
    const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("tempFolderId");                        
    const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("docTemplateId");


    //Get ID of file and open as a document       
    
    const OpenDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());                                                   
    const body =   OpenDoc.getBody();     


   //Get body from the PDF text and replace the keywords based on the response submission  
                                                    
   body.replaceText("{name}", info['Patient Name'][0] );                                                    
   body.replaceText("{report no}", info['Report No'][0]); 
   body.replaceText("{before}", info['Before Treatment Image'][0]);
   body.replaceText("{after}", info['After Treatment Image'][0]);
 

   OpenDoc.saveAndClose();
   

   //Creating a file name based on the report no    
                       
   const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
   const PdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Report No'][0]])  
   tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);                                                                              
}
```

Comment: I think that the images of `https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGXSh.png` and `https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCtYl.png` are the same.

Comment: @Tanaike, the sample pictures are only examples to help understand my situation better. I've edited the post. Do check it out. Is there any way to assist me for this script ?

Comment: Do you get any solution? as i am still facing the problem