# How to Generate PDF of an image response submitted in Google form and send Auto email to the respondent with attachment as PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I am developing a google form which have some text field and image field. Now after submission  I am able to generate pdf of text responses. Also the pdf of responses is sent to the respondent email.

I have referred to this  [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpZGvKIHmR8).

### Script used for text :

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const pdfFile=createPDF(info);
  const entryRow=e.range.getRow();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("People").getRange(entryRow,6).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
  sendEmail(e.namedValues["Email"], pdfFile);    
}
function sendEmail(email, pdfFile){

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Succesfuly filled the form ", {attachments:[pdfFile],name:"Test Case" });
}

function createPDF(info){
const pdfFolder= DriveApp.getFolderById("pdfFolderID");
const tempFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("tempFolderID");
const templateDoc=DriveApp.getFileById("TemplateDOc");
const newTempFile= templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
const openDoc= DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
const body=openDoc.getBody();
body.replaceText("{Fn}", info['Name'][0]);

openDoc.saveAndClose();
const blobPDF= newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile= pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name'][0]+  "_Application for the post" );
tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
return pdfFile;    
}
```

Now I am looking for the solution so that the image  submitted by the respondent on the google form should be inserted in the same document and an auto mail be sent to the respondent.

Similar problem is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65062109/how-do-i-embed-an-image-uploaded-by-form-to-google-doc-auto-generating-pdf)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your script, I cannot understand the relationship between your script and `add image in the PDF.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: the above script is for generating pdf which have text....now i want to know what should i do for image addition

Comment: In wwhich column of the form responses is the rul to the uploaded image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create a placeholder for the image and replace it through an actual image blob retrieved from the url of the uploaded image

Assuming that the URL to the image is contained in the response to the question "Image" and that the placeholder in the template is called "{Image}", modify `function createPdf` as following:

```
function createPDF(info){
    ...
    const body=openDoc.getBody();
    body.replaceText("{Fn}", info['Name'][0]);

    var imageUrl = info['Image'][0];
    var imagePlaceholder = "{Image}";
    var id = imageUrl.match(/[\w\_\-]{25,}/)[0];
    var img = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    var position = body.findText(imagePlaceholder);
    var element = position.getElement();
    element.asText().setText("");
    element.getParent().asParagraph().insertInlineImage(0, img.getBlob());

    openDoc.saveAndClose();
    ...   
}
```

What this code does is:

- Localize the named value correponding to the uploaded image URL
- Obtain the image blob from the URL by opening it with DriveApp
- Find in your template the placeholder reserved for the image
- Replace the text by an empty string
- Retrieve the element that contains the placeholder
- Get the element's parent paragraph
- Insert the image blob into the parent paragraph

In other words, a text placeholder gets replaced by an image.