# Add image in pdf instead of link using app script google form onsubmit

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting image link from google form body.replaceText("{image}", data['Selfie'][0]) from this code but I need to add image to pdf via google doc using app script google.
I've also added image in doc file which is located in front of text and alt text => Title is photo

````
function makePdf(data) {
  let tempFol = "temp folder"
  let pdfFol = "pdf folder"
  let docFile = "doc file"
  let dummyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(docFile).makeCopy(tempFol).setName("DumpFile");
  let openFile = DocumentApp.openById(dummyFile.getId());
  let body = openFile.getBody();
  
  //Logger.log();
  body.replaceText("{image}", data['Selfie'][0])

  body.replaceText("{name}", data['Name'][0])
  body.replaceText("{mob}", data['Mobile No'][0])

  openFile.saveAndClose();
  let blob = dummyFile.getAs('application/pdf').setName(data['Name'][0]+" - "+data['Check-in (Date)'][0]);
  let pdffile =DriveApp.getFolderById(tempFol).createFile(blob);
  pdffile.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(pdfFol));
  DriveApp.getFolderById(tempFol).removeFile(dummyFile);
  return pdffile
}

function formResponce(e){
  let data =e.namedValues;
  let pdffile =makePdf(data);
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  sheet.getRange(row,14).setValue(pdffile.getUrl());
}```
````

Comment: I think that this thread will be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69552686